# Positioning of an image within a row

Tags: graphics, multirow

I am trying to import an image in a row, and then have some text in the row directly beneath it. But because the image is very tall it overlaps with the text below. I have managed to avoid this problem with all the other entries, as you can see in the picture below.

I have tried to create an empty row below the picture, but there is still overlap.

Is there a way to "justify" (not sure if that is the right word) the image in the row so that it aligns itself by placing the bottom of the image with the bottom of the row, rather than the top of the image with the top of the row? Maybe something like {u}?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

%A Few Useful Packages
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{fontspec}                   %for loading fonts
\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,url,parskip}   %other packages for formatting
\usepackage{multicol}
\RequirePackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, left=20mm, right=20mm, top=15mm, bottom=20mm}
\usepackage{supertabular}               %for Grades
\usepackage{titlesec}                   %custom \section

%Setup hyperref package, and colours for links
\usepackage{hyperref}
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour, linkcolor=linkcolour}

\usepackage{multirow}

%FONTS
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
%\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont = Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin}
%%% modified for Karol Kozioł for ShareLaTeX use
\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}


%-------------WATERMARK TEST [**not part of a CV**]---------------
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{30mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\TPHorizModule}
\textblockorigin{2mm}{0.65\paperheight}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

%--------------------BEGIN DOCUMENT----------------------
\begin{document}

%--------------------SECTIONS-----------------------------------
%Section: Personal Data
\section{}
\begin{tabular}{l|l}
    \textrm{Address}   & address \\
    \textrm{Phone}     & number\\
    \textrm{Email}     & email \\
    \textrm{LinkedIn} & .. \\ 
\end{tabular}

%Section: Work Experience
\section{Work Experience}
\begin{tabular}{p{2.2cm}|p{11.5cm}} 

\multirow{3}{*}{\includegraphics[width=1.8cm]{Rio_2016.png}} & \textbf{Rio 2016 Olympics} \emph{Technology Service Desk Team Member} \\ & I volunteered at the Rio 2016 Olympics for the technology team at the archery.\\ Aug 2016 & \begin{itemize}
\item Worked with Atos an official sponsor of the Olympics who serviced all technology at the Olympics.
\item Practised Portuguese with the team I worked with and with the locals that I met in Brazil. 
\end{itemize}\\
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{Kano_company_logo.png} & \textbf{Kano Computing} (London) \emph{Editorial Intern} \\ Jun-Jul 2015 & \\ 

\\\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\\multicolumn{2}{c}{} 
\end{tabular}

%\newpage
%\hypertarget{gmat}{\textsc{Gmat}\setmainfont{LMRoman10 Regular}\textregistered\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont=Fontin-SmallCaps]{Fontin-Regular}}

%\XeTeXpdffile ''GMAT.pdf'' page 1 scaled 800

\end{document}
```

[image: image showing overlap of photo and text]

Comment: please provide complete small document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending `\end{document}. don't forget an essential packages in document preamble. help us to help you ...

Comment: just added those in

Comment: merge your code snippets in one document please. i'm lost in your code snippets ...

Comment: like this? I am not entirely sure what you mean

Comment: your document still not compilable. missing are `\begin{document}` and `table` environment. which one you use, which column types you use ? this document should be *mwe* (minimal working example) which anyone can compile without any changes, guessing about missing  stuff etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest placing the dates in the same cell as the logos, and use  `\raisebox` where necessary:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

%A Few Useful Packages
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{fontspec} %for loading fonts
\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,url,parskip} %other packages for formatting
\usepackage{multicol}
\RequirePackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, left=20mm, right=20mm, top=15mm, bottom=20mm}
\usepackage{supertabular} %for Grades
\usepackage{titlesec} %custom \section

%Setup hyperref package, and colours for links
\usepackage{hyperref}
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour, linkcolor=linkcolour}

\usepackage{multirow}

%FONTS
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
%\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont = Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin}
%%% modified for Karol Kozioł for ShareLaTeX use
\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}

%-------------WATERMARK TEST [**not part of a CV**]---------------
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{30mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\TPHorizModule}
\textblockorigin{2mm}{0.65\paperheight}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

%--------------------BEGIN DOCUMENT----------------------
\begin{document}

%--------------------SECTIONS-----------------------------------
%Section: Personal Data
\section{}
\begin{tabular}{l|l}
    \textrm{Address} & address \\
    \textrm{Phone} & number\\
    \textrm{Email} & email \\
    \textrm{LinkedIn} & .. \\
\end{tabular}

%Section: Work Experience
\section{Work Experience}
\begin{tabular}{p{2.2cm}|p{11.5cm}}

\multirow{2}{=}{\includegraphics[width=1.8cm]{Rio_2016.png}\break\centering Aug 2016 } & \textbf{Rio 2016 Olympics} \emph{Technology Service Desk Team Member} \\%
 & I volunteered at the Rio 2016 Olympics for the technology team at the archery.\\%
  & \begin{itemize}
\item Worked with Atos an official sponsor of the Olympics who serviced all technology at the Olympics.
\item Practised Portuguese with the team I worked with and with the locals that I met in Brazil.
\end{itemize}\\
\raisebox{-0.7\height}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{Kano_company_logo.png}}\medskip\break\centering Jun-Jul 2015 & \textbf{Kano Computing} (London) \emph{Editorial Intern} \\

\\\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\\multicolumn{2}{c}{}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

with dirty trick:

[image]

the first image is to tall ... to come over this by adding empty line in table.

- in document below i first make *mwe* from code (remove all what is not essential to your problem)
- add new package `enumitem` for better formatting list in table
- use features of recent version of the `multirow` package
- package `hyperref` (not ised in *mse* below) should be with rare exception always load last in preamble.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, left=20mm, right=20mm, top=15mm, bottom=20mm}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{enumitem}   % <-- added


\begin{document}

\section{Work Experience}

\begin{tabular}{p{2.2cm}|p{11.5cm}}

\multirow{3}{=}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
            & \textbf{Rio 2016 Olympics} \emph{Technology Service Desk Team Member} \\
            & I volunteered at the Rio 2016 Olympics for the technology team at the archery.
                \\
            &    \\
Aug 2016    &   \begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt,
                                leftmargin=*,
                                before=\vspace{-0.8\baselineskip}
                                ]
            \item Worked with Atos an official sponsor of the Olympics who serviced all technology at the Olympics.
            \item Practised Portuguese with the team I worked with and with the locals that I met in Brazil.
                \end{itemize}\\
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    & \textbf{Kano Computing} (London) \emph{Editorial Intern} \\
Jun-Jul 2015
    & \dots
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```